# Show text when hover over button jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show a line of text under a row of buttons. The text shown depends on the button you hover over. I'm having trouble using `.hover()` and `.show()` with my buttons and my text. I want to have it so the text is on a line below the buttons and if you are not hovering on a button, no text is shown. Once you click the button, the text associated with it stays on the page. I'm using Bootstrap, and as of now I have the classes of the various text possibilities hidden using CSS `display:none`. When I tried to hide them using jQuery under the `document.ready`, I couldn't seem to hide them. Perhaps it is how I have the text set up in the html code? Below is a link to the JSFiddle. Thank you in advance!

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-5ths">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-1"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5ths">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-2"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5ths">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5ths">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-4"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5ths">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-5"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-text">
        <div class="b-1-text b-text">
            <h3>Button 1 Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="b-2-text b-text">
            <h3>Button 2 Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="b-3-text b-text">
            <h3>Button 3 Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="b-4-text b-text">
            <h3>Button 4 Text</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="b-5-text b-text">
            <h3>Button 5 Text</h3>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 $('.btn-1').hover(function(){
    $('.b-1-text').show();
});

  $('.btn-2').hover(function(){
    $('.b-2-text').show();
});  

  $('.btn-3').hover(function(){
    $('.b-3-text').show();
});

  $('.btn-4').hover(function(){
    $('.b-4-text').show();
});

  $('.btn-5').hover(function(){
    $('.b-5-text').show();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-5ths {
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        }

.b-1-text{
      display: none;
    }
.b-2-text{
      display: none;
    }
.b-3-text{
      display: none;
    }
.b-4-text{
      display: none;
    }
.b-5-text{
      display: none;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anbenya/h7fua94s/2/

Comment: I've updated your jsFiddle (something you should have done) with included jQuery and added missing `);` https://jsfiddle.net/h7fua94s/3/

Comment: why don't you simply make a general-purpose `.hidden` (or use some bootstrap's) to hide your elements?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h7fua94s/5/

Comment: Yes, thank you! Didn't realize that about jsFiddle

Comment: @abenya cool I'll submit as an answer. wasn't sure if that's what you were going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this quite a bit and just have a single `$.hover()`. Updated your code to reflect that with a `data-id` attribute on the buttons that will toggle the appropriate text box.

And you can toggle a `.selected` class to the text boxes when you click on a button that will make that text box always shown until you click the button again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.btn').hover(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.b-' + id + '-text').show();
  }, function() {
    $('.b-text').hide();
  }).on('click',function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.b-' + id + '-text').toggleClass('selected');
  });

});
```

```css
.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

.b-text {
  display: none;
}
.selected {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-1" data-id="1"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-2" data-id="2"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle btn-3" data-id="3"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle btn-4" data-id="4"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-5ths">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-5" data-id="5"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row btn-text">
      <div class="b-1-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 1 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-2-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 2 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-3-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 3 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-4-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 4 Text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="b-5-text b-text">
        <h3>Button 5 Text</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there was a missing `(` at the end and secondly JQuery wasn't selected in your JSFiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.btn-1').hover(function() {
    $('.b-1-text').show();
  });

  $('.btn-2').hover(function() {
    $('.b-2-text').show();
  });

  $('.btn-3').hover(function() {
    $('.b-3-text').show();
  });

  $('.btn-4').hover(function() {
    $('.b-4-text').show();
  });

  $('.btn-5').hover(function() {
    $('.b-5-text').show();
  });
})
```